# Year not being included in MS Access date comparison

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have checked some posts on here but none seem to address my exact issue. I have 2 sets of dates I am comparing and it doesnt seem to include the year when processing.

All dates are formatted the same, but anything that is 2018 doesn't show as less than today's date, just the 2019 data.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Active.UTID, Active.[UT Name], Active.Status, Active.[UT Owner SID], Active.[Backup Owner SID], Active.[Business Champion], Active.[Reclassification of Risk], PastDueDate.PastDue 
FROM Active, PastDueDate
WHERE (((Active.[Reclassification of Risk])<[PastDueDate].[PastDue]));
```

Comment: Are the relevant fields datatype dates ?

Comment: Store the dates as Date/Time not as Text.

Comment: When i change the "Data Type" to Date/Time i get an error "Microsoft Access ca't change the data type. There isnt enough disk space or memory." There is plenty so im not sure what the issue is.

Comment: The issue is that you stored the dates as TEXT in a format that (probably) is not comparable and can't be changed to Date/Time now. So the best solution is to create another Date/Time column in the table where you will store each date (either manually or by code as an update) and then delete the old column.

Comment: I changed it to this but still not working

SELECT DISTINCTROW Active.UTID, Active.[UT Name], Active.Status, Active.[UT Owner SID], Active.[Backup Owner SID], Active.[Business Champion], Format([Active].[Reclassification of Risk],"mm/dd/yyyy") AS [Reclassification of Risk], PastDueDate.PastDue
FROM Active, PastDueDate
WHERE (((Format([Active].[Reclassification of Risk],"mm/dd/yyyy"))<[PastDueDate].[PastDue]));

Comment: The format: `mm/dd/yyyy` is **not** comparable.

Comment: If`[Reclassification of Risk],`and`[PastDue]`are now date datatypes just compare them without`Format`(e.g`[Active].[Reclassification of Risk] < [PastDueDate].[PastDue]`). If still text use a compareable format like`yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 0):

Compare date values with date values:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    Active.UTID, 
    Active.[UT Name], 
    Active.Status, 
    Active.[UT Owner SID], 
    Active.[Backup Owner SID], 
    Active.[Business Champion], 
    Format([Active].[Reclassification of Risk],"mm/dd/yyyy") AS [Reclassification of Risk], 
    PastDueDate.PastDue 
FROM 
    Active, 
    PastDueDate 
WHERE 
    [Active].[Reclassification of Risk] < [PastDueDate].[PastDue];
```

If the "date" values are text, convert to Date:

```
WHERE 
    DateValue([Active].[Reclassification of Risk]) < DateValue([PastDueDate].[PastDue]);
```

To check for invalid entries:

```
Select * From YourTable Where Not IsDate([DateField]);
```

Comment: I did this but still not pulling in 2018 data

Comment: Nothing will work _as is_ as long as you store dates as text.

Comment: Getting a type mismatch error with "DateValue([Active].[Reclassification of Risk]) < DateValue([PastDueDate].[PastDue]);"

Comment: You can use `IsDate` to check for valid entries.

Comment: @JoshHudson: some empty/none dates in`[Active].[Reclassification of Risk]`or`[PastDueDate].[PastDue]`?`DateValue("NotADate")`will fail, as it needs a date string as parameter.

Comment: GOT IT! "DateValue" had to go in the select field not Where